# why is there a "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list" error when attempting vector push_back?

Tags: c++, vector, constants, overloading, push-back

I am doing an assignment for a C++ class and I am getting an error when using push back with vector. I honestly cannot find any info on why this isnt working and giving me a "no instance of overloaded function" error

```
 class StudentData {

    class StudyModule {
    private:
        const int studyModuleCode;
        const std::string studyModuleName;
    public:
        StudyModule();
        StudyModule(const StudyModule& copy);
        ~StudyModule();
    };

    private:
        const int studentNumber;
        std::string studentName;
        std::vector<StudyModule*> modules;
    public:
        StudentData();
        StudentData(const StudentData& copy);
        ~StudentData();
        void addModules(const StudyModule& module);
        int howManyModules();
};



void StudentData::addModules(const StudyModule& module)
{
    this->modules.push_back(&module);
}
```

Comment: Pop quiz: those pointers in the vector -- are they pointers to constant or non-constant objects, and are you passing a reference to a constant or a non-constant object to this function?

Comment: Minor quibble: Your function is called `addModules()` (emphasis on plurality), but you can only ever add a single module at a time.

Comment: Bad Rule of 0/3/5 in `StudyModule`. It should be Rule of 0, but 2 of the (not) required functions are declared. `const` private members are pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `addModules()` is declared like this:

```
void addModules(const StudyModule& module);
```

that is, its parameter is a reference to `const` object.

But the vector has a pointer to a non-const object as its template argument:

```
std::vector<StudyModule*> modules;
```

Thus, the compiler issues a message for this statement:

```
this->modules.push_back(&module);
```

because the expression `&module` has the type `const StudyModule *`, ie a pointer to a const object.

Even if you would change the template argument of the vector like this:

```
std::vector<const StudyModule *> modules;
```

your approach will be unsafe, because the user can pass a temporary object of type `StudyModule` to the function. In this case, storing a pointer to this object in the vector will become invalid when the temporary object is destroyed afterwards.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that fixed it all :D such as small detail breaking everything like usual :)